# iOS - How to find users of app nearby, even those users who are not even running the App

Tags: ios, geolocation, gps, bluetooth-lowenergy, multipeer-connectivity

What is the best way to find users nearby?

I know it is easy to detect users when both people are running an app.
But how can I detect users of an app who have terminated it? Basically, one person would start the application and they should be able to detect other people who have downloaded the application nearby, even if the other people do not necessarily have that application open. Also, I want accuracy to about 50 meters, so something like significant changes would not work

Is there any way I can always run in the background so that other apps around could locate different users. This process could start again in the background once an app was terminated, like Core Location does.

I have heard of BLE or Core Bluetooth and was wondering if I could implement that somehow.
Maybe Mutlipeer connectivity too. Perhaps something with iBeacons

Constantly tracking users' gps location would be energy inefficient.

I have tried reading other answers to this topic but they seem outdated.

Comment: You should upload  user locations to your server.

Comment: i already said that constant location monitoring is energy inefficient

Comment: You can send the location like in every 20 second when App is running and after app has been closed you can get reference of the latest location.

Comment: What do you mean by "nearby"?  Significant location change updates are energy efficient and can relaunch your app from a terminated star, but not very accurate. GPS bass updates are more accurate but not energy efficient and will stop if the user terminates your app

Comment: Sorry didn't explain this before, I want accuracy to about 50 meters. Significant location changes is around 500 meters. @Paulw11

Comment: @EmreÖnder No thats not what I want. I want to detect people who are nearby even if they have closed the app. After someone closes the app they may move around so the reference of the last location will be inaccurate

Comment: If you want that accuracy with continual updates then you will need to use normal location updates in the background with the implications of  battery impact.

Comment: You could try with Bluetooth as long as you are only using iOS devices. Range would be limited to about 30m and you can only discover people who come into range; you can't get continuous updates in the background about whether they are still in range

Comment: As I know, apps closed can only send data (location, image etc..) for only 15 second after closed so for getting location info from closed apps cannot be done If It is an usual app. What I mean by usual app is, again as I know, maps apps (like Google Maps, Uber) can send location data even the app is in closed.

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry for the late response. However, what you commented is what I am looking for. I just need to identify people, even if they have the app closed, (but I have it open). I don't need to send them any information. However, they must have some unique identifier. I understand that the bluetooth UIUD will always be broadcasted however, I believe that is always changes so theres no way of keeping track of someone by assigning a UIUD? I guess people have to be continuously advertising something? Could provide more information about the idea you presented in your comment?

Comment: You would need to set up your app to act as BLE peripheral in the background using `CBPeripheralManager`. The peripheral could have a characteristic which was a UUID that your app creates; this wouldn't change.  Your "discovery" app would need to connect to the other app via bluetooth in order to retrieve the UUID characteristic.

Comment: @Paulw11 Would it still work though if they completely terminated the app but left their bluetooth on?

Comment: No.  If they terminate the app then the advertising stops.